# How to run a python face recognition script from a php file?

Tags: php, python-3.x, face-recognition

I have a python face recognition script that uses opencv and face_recognition module to detect and match faces.
I want to implement this via a php file. So that whenever the php file is opened the face recognition script starts and opens the open-cv window. However all i am getting is a blank page. The script runs if it has only print("hello world") written in it. But the real script wont start using the same method.
I have both the php and python files in the same directory.

The php codes i have tried are :

```
<?php
$command_exec = escapeshellcmd('python test.py');
$str_output = shell_exec($command_exec);
echo $str_output;
?>
```

This one just prints the first print line of the program which says "now opening face recognition window"

```
<?php
$command_exec = escapeshellcmd('python test.py');
shell_exec($command_exec);
?>
```

This one just gives a blank page

I was expecting the face recognition window to open as it would if i ran the python script directly

Now the thing is I am not supposed to use opencv-php. Neither can i implement the face recognition directly on the webpage. For my purposes i need to run the python script from the php file and then run the face recognition.

Comment: If you run a program from a PHP script, that program then runs on the server and doesn't have any access to your local machine's GUI.

Comment: I see.What could be the closest alternaive?